# Ionic 3 slow starting app on some device android

Tags: ionic-framework

I’m tried create new blank project ionic and after that I straight add android device with syntax ‘ionic cordova platform add android’, and in my file ‘main.ts’ I add some code 'enableProdMode().

Then I run to my device with syntax ‘cordova run android’ and ‘cordova run android --prod’. But the problem is in my first device (xiaomi mi 5) time of starting app is 5 second (I think that normal), but in my second device (samsung galaxy pro) time of starting app is about 20second (I think that not normal, it’s too long for open apps). So how to boost time starting app in some device which is too long open app?

note : there no other code, I just create project and run
Thanks

Comment: Can you share what versions are you using for ionic framework / angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the performance on the start you must implement the lazy loading using [ionic page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) like this https://blog.paulhalliday.io/ionic-3-lazy-loading-components/

And turn off the components you don't need on the start.

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'my-page',
  priority: 'off'
})
```

Another way is using the method `ngOnInit()` to leave the constructor clean and execute some functions after the component has start.

Comment: nice!! that save my life. thank u!!
Note : but I not add `name: 'my-page', priority: 'off'` in `@IonicPage`

Comment: Inside `@IonicPage` those are some optional tags, change the name and priority as you want, and another interesting tag from `@IonicPage` is `segment` because it is used for [deplinking](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/)